# playwright sometimes getting message -Error: Test ended. Browser logs: - in test.afterEach

Tags: playwright

playwright sometimes getting  message  -Error: Test ended. Browser logs: - in test.afterEach .
Is there a reason why?

Playwright Version: "@playwright/test": "1.40.0"
Google Chrome : Version 119.0.6045.160
Browser: Operating System: [Windows 11]

`Error: Test ended.
Browser logs:

C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-component-update --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate,HttpsUpgrades --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --disable-search-engine-choice-screen --user-data-dir=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright_chromiumdev_profile-lPctmM --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
 pid=6408`

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Generally, this means you've forgotten to `await` a promise, as in [Getting Error: page.goto: Test ended. in playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78081979/getting-error-page-goto-test-ended-in-playwright).