# Getting Error: page.goto: Test ended. in playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright, playwright-typescript

I am trying to create a function like this in playwright. By the way, I am new to playwright.

```
import { expect } from "@playwright/test";
import { EnvCredentials } from "../helpers/getEnvCredentials";

export class PW {
    static async visit(page, routeName) {
       await page.goto(EnvCredentials.getCredsValue("BASE_URL") + routeName);
    }
}
```

That visit() method above is being called in this function

```
static async uiLogin(username, password, page) {
   const loginPage = new LoginPage(page);

   PW.visit(page, route_root_page);
   await loginPage.enterUsername(username);
   await loginPage.enterPassword(password);
   await loginPage.clickLoginBtn();
}
```

Upon running, I am getting this error

> Error: page.goto: Test ended.
> Call log:
>
> - navigating to "https://latest.frankiefinancial.io/", waiting until "load"
>   at portal\helpers\playwrightMethods.ts:6
>   4 | export class PW {
>   5 |     static async visit(page, routeName) {
>   6 |         await page.goto(EnvCredentials.getCredsValue("BASE_URL") + routeName);
>   |                    ^
>   7 |     }
>   8 |

[image]

Comment: what values are you passing in to the uiLogin function?  Is `page` a [Playwright page](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page) object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `visit` function is `async` so you should wait for it to complete in your test `await PW.visit(page, route_root_page);`.